# CPLEX and Bluemix integration

Tags: ibm-cloud, cplex, docplexcloud

I am new to Bluemix and I want to use Cplex. I want to know if it is possible to integrate Cplex with Bluemix framework? Any examples are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

IBM provides another cloud based service to run CPLEX - Decision Optimization on Cloud, or DOcloud.

There are [Java and REST APIs available](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/docs/) to access this service, so you could create an application on Bluemix that utilizes these.

https://onboarding-oaas.docloud.ibmcloud.com/software/analytics/docloud/

Comment: A very nice demo of CPLEX and BLUEMIX at http://docrossrates.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/

Answer (score 0):

IBM just announced **Decision Optimization Beta service on IBM Bluemix** so this should be a more straightforward solution to your need.

To experiment with the beta service, you’ll need a Bluemix account. You can sign up for a 30-day free trial.

You can find the [Decision Optimization for Bluemix service in the Bluemix catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/decision-optimization/) and read [the documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/DecisionOptimization/DecisionOptimization.html).

More information on https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/decision-optimization-for-bluemix